# what's the bn client for the contentprovidernative?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-binder

I see the source code in contentproviderNative.java . there is a method called openAssetFile(),and has a field called remote.transact(); I  know I should find the c++ file for the method ,but which c++ file should I read?

Comment: it's a IBinder,  isn't it?

Comment: yes！it's a IBinder!but I don't know how to find the match c++ file @pskink

Comment: so its java object,  what do you want to achieve?

Comment: but the method transact in a remote way,I want to know which remote method was called.

Comment: i don't understand you,  method "transact" is called

Comment: see http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/ContentProviderNative.java, line 609

Comment: You know IBinder, you must know how to use binder to transform message from java to c++(maybe call bp->bn).and the proxy will wait for the native method replay . I want to know which native method called?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59707/discussion-between-ihsan-gaozp-and-pskink).